# Solving series solution near a regular singular point: $2xy''+y'+xy=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

*Disclaimer: I hate series. Burn it to the ground. Why do we even need to study this?*

Ok, so I haven an equation $2xy''+y'+xy=0$. The idea is to solve it using the series and euler equations learned from previous chapters.

I found my p(x) and q(x), limits of xp(x) and $x^2q(x)$, both limits exist, which means x=0 is a regular singular point. I then get the following Euler's equation:

$2x^2y''+p_0xy'+q_0y=0$

And here comes the fun part. I am fairly sure I've messed up the series calculations.

**On line 6 I substitute series and its derivatives into the original equation**

[image]

For $x^{n+r}$ I get:
$a_n={a_{n-2} \over (n+r)(n+r-1)+(n+r)}$

*Did I make a mistake somewhere, if so where? I know how to proceed with solving the differential equation once I get all my $a_n$*.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I provide a solution for $2xy''+y'+xy=0$, can you do the Euler part as I have no idea what you are trying to do there?

Comment: Note that $$a_n = \frac{a_{n-2}}{(n+r)(n+r-1)+(n+r)} = \frac{a_{n-2}}{(n+r)^2}.$$ This will make the deduction of the recurrence  relation much easier. Also, you have to use the [indicial equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IndicialEquation.html) to determine the value of $r$.